# no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "NULL" in dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am developing a shiny application for data aggregation where values are fetched from database and aggregations are made with dplyr package. Initially when there is no data I need to handle this error in better way by showing `zero` value on screen or `NA` value instead of this error in red `no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

```
output$Regbycity <- renderValueBox({
valueBox(

  value = reg_city()$Total[1],
  subtitle = reg_city()$registrant_city[1],
  icon = icon("globe"),
  color = "light-blue"
)
})

 reg_city <- function(){
   final_data %>% 
     group_by(registrant_city) %>%
     summarise(Total= n()) %>% 
     arrange(desc(Total)) %>% 
     top_n(n=15)

  }
```

In above code value object does not hole anything as there is nothing in database and this is the line where it displays error on shiny dashboard which I want to get rid off. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function like this....

```
if.is.empty <- function(x){
    is.null(need(x, message = FALSE))}
```

and your codes looks like this....

```
reg_city <- function(){
    if (if.is.empty(final_data)) {
        final_data %>% 
        group_by(registrant_city) %>%
        summarise(Total= n()) %>% 
        arrange(desc(Total)) %>% 
        top_n(n=15)}
}
```

Note. Just be careful with the indentation...

This worked for me in a shiny app when it begins without info.